# preg_replace internal link

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

how do I do when I want to preg_replace a href, but only if it's my own?

```
$a = 'href="http://mysite.com/?s=Bananas&lang=en"';
$host = 'http://mysite.com';
$a = preg_replace('#href="'.$host.'\/?[(s|p)]=([.*?])&lang=([.*?])"#e','href="index.php#$1\/$2\\lang\/$3"',$a);
//The result I want:
echo  $a;
//Becomes href="http://mysite.com/#s/Bananas\\lang/en"
```

But what am I doing wrong? 
This regex-syntax is very difficult...

Comment: What do you exactly want? Please write the output you want.

Comment: This: `href="http://mysite.com/#s/Bananas\\lang/en"`

Comment: Do NOT use `e` (PREG_REPLACE_EVAL) modifier in your regex patterns unless you are 100% sure what you are doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = 'href="http://mysite.com/?s=Bananas&lang=en"';
$host = 'http://mysite.com';
echo preg_replace('#href="'.preg_quote($host).'/\?(s|p)=(.*?)&lang=(.*?)"#','href="'.$host.'/#$1/$2\\\\\lang/$3"',$a);
?>
```

This seems to work for me :)